# Two try statements with the same except clause

Tags: python, try-catch

Say I want to do something in python 3 with a two character string like "A1" or "1A" but first check if it's in either form beacuse the user may type it in both ways. (I already have a way to check if a char is a letter.)

How would I implement this in the shortest and easiest way?
I would like to try one thing, and if it fails, try another before raising the exception. Like so:

```
x = 0
string = 'A1'
try:
    x = int(string[1]) # Check that second char is a digit
    # something else to check first char is a letter
else try:
    x = int(string[0]) # Check that first char is a digit
    # something else to check second char is a letter
except:
    print('Was in neither form')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a loop:

```
for i in range(1, -1, -1):
    try:
        string[i] = int(string[i])
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        break
else:
    print('Was in neither form')
```

If either conversion succeeds, the loop is broken out of with `break`. If you didn't use `break`, the `else` suite on the `for` loop is executed.

However, you cannot assign to string indices as they are immutable. A better option would be to use a regular expression:

```
import re

valid_pattern = re.compile('^(?:\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]\d)$')
def is_valid(string):
    return valid_pattern.match(string) is not None
```

Comment: Why doesn't it `break` if the `except` is entered? Shouldn't it be in an `else`?

Comment: Shouldn't the "except" have a `continue` statement?

Comment: @AlexThornton: because I'm an idiot? I forgot the `else` or `continue` options.

Comment: Ofcourse I can't assign to that. My bad. Tried to make a more general question than the specific I had but mixed up things. I will quickly edit to be more clear. Though, please explain the continue part a bit more as I'm unfamiliar with how that works.

Comment: @Jaxxo: an explicit `continue` would move on to the next iteration of the loop. So rather than `pass` you could use `continue` to skip the rest of the loop body to move to the next iteration, at which point you could remove the `else:` from the `try:` and unindent the `break`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper to reduce the nesting:

```
def letter_and_digit(identifier):
    a, b = identifier

    try:
        return a, int(b)
    except ValueError:
        return b, int(a)

try:
    letter, digit = letter_and_digit(string)
    assert letter.isupper()
except:
    print('Was in neither form')
```

A regular expression also works, but might be overkill:

```
import re
LETTER_DIGIT_PAIR = re.compile('^(?=.?([A-Z]))(?=.?([0-9]))..$')
letter, digit = LETTER_DIGIT_PAIR.match('A1').groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

For variety, this approach does not use try/except.  It simply verifies that `string` has exactly one digit and one letter:

```
if not (sum(c.isdecimal() for c in string) == 1 and sum(c.isalpha() for c in string) == 1):
    print('Was in neither form')
```